# Perl scalar and json

Tags: json, perl, hash, scalar

I'm not sure what the below is doing exactly at the:

> scalar %{ $units}

in the below:

```
 if ( defined( $units ) && scalar %{ $units} ) {
```

The script runs most of the entries, but it appears when it gets to the end it comes up with this error.

> hash- or arrayref expected (not a simple scalar, use allow_nonref to
>   allow this) at /usr/share/perl5/JSON.pm line 154.

I cannot share much more of the code due to restraints, but I'm trying to fix this so that that error does not arise, but I lack the understanding of the above use  of:

> scalar %{ $units }

To properly diagnose what is going on at this stage.

It would appear that this is an array of hashes and we are checking if it has anything in it?

A comment above this line says:

```
# We only want to move on if there were units for this timeframe
```

Comment: That line would be much better written as `if( 'HASH' eq ref $units && scalar keys %$units ) {...`, because it seems to want to verify that `$units` contains a hashref, and that the hash it refers to contains elements.

Comment: @DavidO: I don't see reason to assume the code is trying to verify that it contains a hashref; looks to me just like it assumes it is a hashref (and the OP isn't indicating getting an error there of the sort that would happen if that was a bad assumption)

Comment: This is why you should always `use strict;`. If `$units` is not a hash reference, you would get a compile error like `Can't use string ("foo") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at prog.pl line 10.` with strict enabled.

Comment: strict is on and is not causing an error

Comment: @KirsKringle Then `$units` *is* a hash reference, and the JSON module is complaining about something else. Since you haven't shown the code that actually triggers the error (your snippet doesn't use `JSON.pm` at all), I would recommend running your script with the [debugger](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) and putting a breakpoint on line 154 of `JSON.pm` to sniff out the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is testing to see if $units is defined, and if it is, assuming it is a hashref and testing to see if the hash is non-empty.

The `scalar` here has no effect, since the if gives the && operation scalar context and && passes that context on to its left operand, so `%{$units}` would have scalar context anyway.   A hash in scalar context produces a false value if the hash is empty and a true value (a string describing bucket usage, but usually it doesn't matter what it is except that it is true) if it is not empty.

Comment: this is indeed what I was looking for and understanding, but I could not find the reason for the scalar.  Is there any possibility that this test to see if it is empty would miss some condition as it would appear by the error that a ref is empty and acted upon which causes an issue with the json encoding that is later called in the block.

Comment: You might normally use something like `scalar @array` to get a count of array elements. I suspect this is following the same (but incorrect) thought process.

Comment: @Kirs Kringle, Lots of people like to use `scalar` where it's not needed. Even when they know it's not needed. They probably have problems grasping the fact that an array or hash can evaluate to a scalar.

Comment: the error you are getting doesn't indicate a reference to an empty hash, it indicates something that isn't a reference at all.

Comment: So from your info I found that in another script it was passing this as a normal $ and not a % .  Therefore it was confused on the ref for some reason.  It is weird it worked for most of them, but quit out on some.  Now it works, but when I run the secondary script it says the way it is denounced is depreciated, but it works completely so I'm going to leave it.  Thanks for the help.